# Translating imperative Algorithm to Elixir

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, elixir

I have an algorithm in python which I need to implement in a functional programming language, Elixir.

**input:**

- list of tuples: `[("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ..., ("E", "F")]`
- list of booleans: `[False, True, True, False, True]`

  - indicate whether a tuple is valid or not
  - `("A", "B")` valid  ,  `("B", "C")` invalid, ...

**output:**

- `[["A"],  ["B",  "C",  "D"],  ["E", "F"]]`

  - nested list of grouped tokens
  - `A` does not have a connection -> single item
  - `B, C, D` have a connection -> grouped together

#### Basically I want to translate this python sample code to Elixir:

```py
input = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
tuples = list(zip(input, input[1:]))
# --> [("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ..., ("E", "F")]

# this is a black box -> database result
results = [False, True, True, False, True]

[first_item, *_] = input
biglist = []; smalllist = [first_item]
for (left, right), result in zip(tuples, results):
    if result:
        # valid tuple, keep filling current bucket
        smalllist.append(right)
    else:
        # invalid tuple
        biglist.append(smalllist)
        smalllist = [right]
        
if len(smalllist) > 0:
    biglist.append(smalllist)

print(biglist)
[["A"],  ["B",  "C",  "D"],  ["E", "F"]]
#     fls,   tru,  tru,   fls,   tru
```

What is the Elixir-way for that problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You ask about elixir but the code you've shown is in python. Are you trying to translate this working python code into elixir code? If so, please state that explicitly in your question.

Comment: The python code is an example, as I thought a lengthy explanation may not help. I added more info, thanks for the insight

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact transliteration. There's probably a much better way to do it though, maybe I'll come back to it later if nobody else does.

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  def run do
    input = ~w(A B C D E F)
    tuples = Enum.zip(input, tl(input))

    results = [false, true, true, false, true]
    combined = Enum.zip(tuples, results)

    first_item = hd(input)
    small_list = [first_item]
    big_list = []

    {small_list, big_list} =
      Enum.reduce(combined, {small_list, big_list}, fn
        {{_left, right}, true}, {small_list, big_list} ->
          {[right | small_list], big_list}

        {{_left, right}, false}, {small_list, big_list} ->
          {[right], [Enum.reverse(small_list) | big_list]}
      end)

    case small_list do
      [] -> big_list
      _ -> [Enum.reverse(small_list) | big_list]
    end
    |> Enum.reverse()
  end
end
```

Output:

```elixir
[["A"], ["B", "C", "D"], ["E", "F"]]
```

Comment: This is already helpful, thanks! I did not know about `~w()` and how `tl()` can be used here

Answer (score 2):

A similar solution, using `Enum.chunk_while/4`

```elixir
defmodule Chunky do
  def collect([], _), do: []

  def collect([hd | rest], acceptance_list) do
    rest
    |> Enum.zip(acceptance_list)
    |> Enum.chunk_while(
      [hd],
      fn
        {next, true}, candidate_list ->
          {:cont, [next | candidate_list]}
        {next, false}, candidate_list ->
          {:cont, Enum.reverse(candidate_list), [next]}
      end,
      fn
        [] = acc -> {:cont, acc}
        [_ | _] = candidate_list -> {:cont, Enum.reverse(candidate_list), []}
      end
    )
  end
end
```

I skipped the first zip because the value from it was being ignored anyway (Missed that the first several passes through).

In the first pattern match case in the chunk_while, in the event the prior acceptance was false, we replace the sublist with the "next" item and emit the reversed chunk.

For the second case, in the event the prior acceptance was false, we replace the sublist with the "next" item and emit the reversed chunk.

A small caveat to this approach is that, under the covers, chunk_while does more or less what Adam's solution does: it reverses the list each chunk. So effectively this requires an additional reversal behind the scenes, which doesn't cost that much with this data size but might of concern for larger lists.

Although it's possible it will demand slightly less cognitive load.

I turned this into a `/2` function just for my own convenience while testing; you can run it like this:

```elixir
list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
acceptance = [false, true, true, false, true]

Chunky.collect(list, acceptance)
```

I did not do it in the example above, because the overhead added wasn't worth it given the small list size, but for larger lists you may find it useful to replace the `Enum.xyz` functions with their `Stream.xyz` equivalents.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, interesting insights as well.
I can't help, but feel like the functional solution is a lot more complex. Instead of the side effects I need to worry about the "invisible paths" that my data takes from one function to the next. Maybe that is just my lack of experience with Elixir

Comment: @jnnks I don't think you particularly need to worry about the invisible paths I described unless you run into a performance issue, the same as you only need to worry about implementation details of libraries you call if you run into a leaky abstraction or performance issue in any other language. But it certainly can take some time to find natural-feeling idioms for a lot of problems. I worry about that long before I think about the hidden side effects/implementation details :P

Answer (score 0):

I came up with my own solution after some more Elixir training that avoids anonymous functions and uses tail recursion:

```py
tokens = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
connections = [false, true, true, true, true]

defmodule Builder do
  def run(tokens, conns) do
    # use the first token as group
    {:ok, groups} = group(tl(tokens), conns, [hd(tokens)], [])
    Enum.reverse(groups)
  end

  # no more tokens and conns -> all good
  defp group([], [], group, all_groups), do: {:ok, [Enum.reverse(group) | all_groups]}
  
  # something is wrong, unequal amount of tokens and conns
  defp group(_, [], _, _), do: {:error, "too many tokens"} 
  defp group([], _, _, _), do: {:error, "too many conns"}

  # process tokens with tail recursion
  defp group([t | tokens], [valid_connection | conns], group, all_groups) do
    if valid_connection do
      # add token to current group
      group(tokens, conns, [t | group], all_groups) 
    else
      # add group to final list and start new group
      group(tokens, conns, [t], [Enum.reverse(group) | all_groups])
    end
  end
end

Builder.run(tokens, connections)
```